# How would I select a selector in CSS that changes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape movie titles from [Tmdb](https://www.themoviedb.org/?language=en) but each title has a different selector. Is there a way for me to get them all in one go?

For example: The css selector for [Birdman](https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/194662-birdman?language=en) is .7, [Star Wars](https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/11-star-wars?language=en) is .9, and other movies have different ones.

You may ask why not just got the titles like [this](https://www.themoviedb.org/movie?page=3&language=en) but it is because I need to go on each page in order to get the genre as well.

```
class PosterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "movieposter - imgsearch"
   start_urls = ["https://www.themoviedb.org/?language=en"]

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.css('.logo~ li:nth-child(3) > a').xpath('//*~[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "logo", " " ))]//li[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 3) and parent::*)]//>//a')
        yield scrapy.Request(url.xpath("@href").extract_first(), self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        """
        Method to press the 'next' button and go through each movie poster
        """

        for href in response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "view_more", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "result", " " ))]'):
            yield scrapy.Request(href.xpath('@href').extract_first(), self.parse_covers)

        next = response.css('.glyphicons-circle-arrow-right').xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "glyphicons-circle-arrow-right", " " ))]')
        yield scrapy.Request(next.xpath("@href").extract_first(), self.parse_page)

    def parse_covers(self, response):
        img = response.css('.zoom a').xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "zoom", " " ))]//a')

        # what to put for this selector?
        title = response.css().extract_first()

        genre = response.css('.genres a').extract_first()

        yield MoviePoster(title=title, genre = genre, file_urls=[])
```

Comment: this is the deal of scrapping ... you don't have control of the pages, so you need to adjust your code each time things changes

Comment: `.title h2` ? Start one level up then go by the actual element tag instead of its class.

Comment: Is this something that can't be done [with their api](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api?language=en)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when a site has an API (and it has the information you are looking for), you should use it instead of webscraping. [TheMovieDB API](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) seems to allow 4 requests per second and took only a minute to sign up.

This script below (written with `Python 3.6.4`) uses `total_pages=100` (you could set up to a maximum of `1000` as per API) and each page has 20 movies returned as JSON. I had to make a separate API call to get the human-readable genres but everything seems to work fine. For `100` pages, this code took about `40sec` to run and then all the results are saved to a file for you to work with later.

```
import json
import time

import requests


class PopularMovies:
    API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    BASE_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3'

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.genres = self._get_genres()
        self.popular_movies = []

    def _get_genres(self):
        params = {'api_key': self.API_KEY}
        r = self.session.get(
            '{}/genre/movie/list'.format(self.BASE_URL),
            params=params
        )
        r.raise_for_status()
        result = {}
        for genre in r.json()['genres']:
            result[genre['id']] = genre['name']
        return result

    def _add_readable_genres(self):
        for i in range(len(self.popular_movies)):
            current = self.popular_movies[i]
            genre_ids = current['genre_ids']
            current.update({
                'genres': sorted(self.genres[g_id] for g_id in genre_ids)
            })

    def _get_popular_movies_page(self, *, page_num):
        params = {
            'api_key': self.API_KEY,
            'page': page_num,
            'sort_by': 'popularity.desc'
        }
        r = self.session.get(
            '{}/discover/movie'.format(self.BASE_URL),
            params=params
        )
        r.raise_for_status()
        return r.json()

    def get_popular_movie_pages(self, *, total_pages=1):
        if not (1 <= total_pages <= 1000):
            raise ValueError('total_pages must be between 1-1000')

        for page_num in range(1, total_pages + 1):
            movies = self._get_popular_movies_page(page_num=page_num)
            self.popular_movies.extend(movies['results'])
            time.sleep(0.25)  # 40 requests every 10 seconds, 1 every 0.25sec

        self._add_readable_genres()

    def write_to_file(self, *, filename='popular_movies.json'):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.popular_movies, f, indent=4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    movies = PopularMovies()
    movies.get_popular_movie_pages(total_pages=100)
    movies.write_to_file()

    # just to show that you can easily pick out the data you want
    with open('popular_movies.json', 'r') as f:
        movies = json.load(f)
        for i, movie in enumerate(movies, start=1):
            print('Title:\n\t{}'.format(movie['title']))
            print('Genre:')
            for genre in movie['genres']:
                print('\t{}'.format(genre))
            print('-' * 20)
```

The console output of this script was too long to put in this question [but here is a link to it](https://bpaste.net/show/c94141fe810a).

Also, [here is a link to `popular_movies.json`](https://bpaste.net/show/d81a71bd8cc5) to show how much extra information you get for each movie (allowing you to expand in the future to more than just titles and genres).

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked for but a method for doing what you want, I think.

The usual preliminaries:

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/movie?page=3&language=en').text
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

Now use `find_all` with a Python function to identify elements whose `id` attributes match 'movie_'.

```
>>> def movie_id(id):
...     return id and bs4.re.compile(r'^movie_').match(id)
... 
>>> movies = soup.find_all(id=movie_id)
```

There are 61 of them in the page you highlighted for consideration.

```
>>> len(movies)
61
```

Here's the content of the first item.

```
>>> movies[0]
<a alt="Inside Out" class="result" href="/movie/150540?language=en" id="movie_150540" title="Inside Out">
<img alt="Inside Out" class="poster lazyload fade" data-sizes="auto" data-src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2/aAmfIX3TT40zUHGcCKrlOZRKC7u.jpg" data-srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2/aAmfIX3TT40zUHGcCKrlOZRKC7u.jpg 1x, https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2/aAmfIX3TT40zUHGcCKrlOZRKC7u.jpg 2x"/>
<div class="meta">
<span class="hide popularity_rank_value" id="popularity_50cdfd9c19c2957b79385f6e_value">
<div class="tooltip_popup popularity">
<h3>Popularity Rank</h3>
<p>Today: 42</p>
<p>Last Week: 132</p>
</div>
</span>
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-cardio x1 popularity_rank" id="popularity_50cdfd9c19c2957b79385f6e"></span>
<span class="right">
</span>
</div>
</a>
```

You can dig out the title in this way.

```
>>> movies[0].attrs['title']
'Inside Out'
```